# Convert 3D volumetic data into 3D mesh data in VTK

Tags: 3d, volume, mesh, vtk

I have a 3D volumetic data segmented from CT image, and want to directly convert that 3D volumetic data into vtk 3D mesh data (perhaps, vtkPolyData something like that).  This 3D volumetic data is not spherical topology, instead it has a few holes in it.

Does someone help me what vtk function/class should I use for it?

Answer (score 0):

I've only used vtk to do volume isosurface rendering from a Python vtk wrapper (mayavi/mlab), but that might give some hints for whatever your environment is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6031871/24283

Comment: Thank you timday. Yes, it gives me a lot of hints and insight.