# Plot a 2D vertical plane from interpolation of x,y,z numpy defining a vertical plane. Python/Mayavi

Tags: python, numpy, mayavi

I have 3 numpy arrays as follow:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

x = np.arange(0,101,1)
a = np.arange(0,51,1)
b = np.arange(51,76,0.5)
z = np.hstack((a,b))

y = np.zeros(x.shape)
values = np.random.random(x.shape)
```

They define a vertical plane that I would like to plot as a colormap.
Any idea on how to do that using Mayavi and Python?

I tried different things based on the http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_surface_from_irregular_data.html example but I am stuck with the fact that the plane is vertical...

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6031871/3419103?)?

Comment: You want to "plot a vertical plane as a colormap?" I don't know what that means. For a useful answer please better clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also look at `mlab.imshow`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't understand your question but I can't seem to pick out the 3D data that you describe; `values` is a 1D array in your code. So here is an example I made up:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

If you have a 3D array of random data:

```
data = np.random.normal(loc=100,scale=10,size=(101,101,101))
```

And you want a colour map of a 2D slice, say at y=0, you can use `imshow` - no need for mayavi:

```
plt.imshow(data[:,0,:],cmap='Reds')
```

This gives (random noise in this case):

[image]